# How to use -filter_complex and -vf together in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to use `-filter_complex` and `-vf` together in one line but I can't do that and get error.

First code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.87*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.15[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" e1.mp4
```

Second code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" e1.mp4
```

So I combine two code above together. Combined code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.87*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.15[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" e1.mp4
```

I can can't run code I get the error:

```
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `-filter_complex`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black,setpts=0.87*PTS;[0:a]atempo=1.15" output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) and the additional documentation in the link.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your answer is the best that can help me. Now I can run it.

Comment: If I add this code : ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf hflip -c:a copy ouput.mp4 To above code How can I do that sir?

Comment: @ChhengRavy `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]hflip,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black,setpts=0.87*PTS;[0:a]atempo=1.15" output.mp4`

Comment: Million Thanks Brother. You save my time. Wish You good luck. Now my problem is solved.